# Is VS Code auto bracket closing feature working for you?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The VS Code auto closing brackets feature is not working for me.

Whenever I type `(`, it won't close it and I have to do it manually.
Even when I set my `auto closing brackets settings` to always.

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this issue? And is the same issue happening with any of you?

Comment: Maybe some extension messes up with keybindings or overrides the default `type` command? Does it work when running with extensions disabled `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: yes then it is working but then how will i identify which extension is messing it up

Comment: and how to enable extensions again?

Comment: They will be disabled temporarily. Actually, you can run `Help: Start Extension Bisect` from Command Palette to start searching which extension is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

For me Github Copilot was creating the problem, if anyone else is having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Github Copilot maybe that is the problem. I uninstall that and problem solved